# DOJO : help me with tab

Tags: html, tabs, dojo

I want to open the link `myDiv1` just one time (one click) excepted if its close:

1) If I click on `myDiv1` --> open a new tab ("Dashboard 1") --> It works

2) If I click on `onClose` from `myDiv1` --> close tab ("Dashboard 1") --> It works

3) If the new tab ("Dashboard 1") is open and I click again on `myDiv1` I just want to select the tab and not to create a new one.

How can i do the third step???

Kiss from Paris

```
<script>
require(["dojo/dom-attr", "dojo/query", "dijit/layout/TabContainer",      "dijit/layout/ContentPane", "dojo/on", "dojo/dom", "dojo/dom-style", "dojo/mouse", "dojo/dom-construct"], 

function(attr, query, TabContainer, ContentPane, on, dom, domStyle, mouse, domConstruct)
{   
    on(myDiv1, "click", function(evt)
    {
        var cp1 = new ContentPane(
        {
            title: myDiv1.innerText,
            closable: true,
            onClose: function()
            {
                tc.removeChild(cp1);
            },
            content: domConstruct.create("iframe", 
            { 
                "src": "http://www.bing.com/"
            })
        });
        tc.addChild(cp1, 0);
        tc.selectChild(cp1);
    }); 

    var tc = new TabContainer(
    {
        style: "height: 100%; width: 100%;"
    }, "tab-window");
    tc.startup();

});
</script>

</head>
<body class="claro">
    <div style="float:left; width:10%; height:100%">
        <div id="myDiv1" data-dojo-type="dijit/MenuItem" style="padding:5px; color:blue; font-size:125%;">Dashboard 1</div>
    </div>

<div id="idonglet" style="float:left; width:90%; height:500px">
    <div id="tab-window">
        <!--<iframe id="myIframe" style="float:left; width:100%; height:100%"></iframe>-->
        <div id="output"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the children of the `TabContainer` and iterate over them and check if the title of any of them is equal to `myDiv1.innerText`. If it is, then select that child.

I am posting here, the changes that are required in your code.

```
require(["dojo/dom-attr", "dojo/query", "dijit/layout/TabContainer",      "dijit/layout/ContentPane", "dojo/on", "dojo/dom", "dojo/dom-style", "dojo/mouse", "dojo/dom-construct", "dijit/registry"], 

function(attr, query, TabContainer, ContentPane, on, dom, domStyle, mouse, domConstruct, registry)
{   
    on(myDiv1, "click", function(evt)
    {
        var found= false;
        var children= tc.getChildren();
        for(var i=0; i<children.length; i+++){
             var child= children[i];
             if(child.title== myDiv1.innerText){
                  tc.selectChild(child);
                  found= true;
                  break;
             }
        }
        if(!found){
            var cp1 = new ContentPane({
                title: myDiv1.innerText,
                closable: true,
                onClose: function()
                {
                    tc.removeChild(cp1);
                },
                content: domConstruct.create("iframe", 
                { 
                    "src": "http://www.bing.com/"
                })
            });
            tc.addChild(cp1, 0);
            tc.selectChild(cp1);
        }
    }); 

    var tc = new TabContainer(
    {
        style: "height: 100%; width: 100%;"
    }, "tab-window");
    tc.startup();

});
```